# How do we properly use a polymer property in a script tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, polymer

Working on a web component that builds on top of connections with socket.io but we want the user to be able to link to their own version of socket.io from their server. Using the following script:

`<script src$="{{socketIp}}/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

`socketIp` is defined and the page can load it fine. An example is "http://localhost:8080"

Using `src=` will give a 404 and print out the "{" in the url. Using `src$=` seems to be the right way of doing things since it can then successfully load the link.

On attached we are then referencing `io` but it results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`.

Entering the link directly works fine but when used as a variable it doesn't work.
We attempted using a timeout as well in case it was an issue with it not being loaded yet but that also did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Bind to the `<script>`'s load event with `on-load="METHOD"`, where `METHOD` is the name of a method on your Polymer object. `socket.io` should be defined within that callback method.

This example binds `onScriptLoad()` and `onScriptError()` as callbacks to the `<script>`'s `on-load` and `on-error`, respectively:

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
  <template>
    <script src$="{{src}}"
            on-load="onScriptLoad"
            on-error="onScriptError"></script>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-foo',
      onScriptLoad: function() {
        console.log('script loaded');
      },
      onScriptError: function(e) {
        console.log('script err:', e);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.6/socket.io.min.js"></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <script src$="{{src}}"
              on-load="onScriptLoad"
              on-error="onScriptError"></script>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        onScriptLoad: function() {
          console.log('socket.io:script loaded');

          var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
          socket.on('connect', function(e) {
              console.log('socket.io:connected:', e);
            })
            .on('connect_error', function(e) {
              console.log('socket.io:connection error:', e.message);
            })
            .on('news', function(data) {
              console.log('socket.io:news:', data);
            });
        },
        onScriptError: function(e) {
          console.log('socket.io:script err:', e);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/safadi/edit?html,console)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just load the script imperatively:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = ip + '/socket.io/socket.io.js';
e.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(e);
e.onload = function() {
  // work with socket.io
};
```

Comment: This would work fine in normal cases but I actually have some observers that are working with socket io. socket.io would need to be loaded before those get fired.

Comment: quick solution: remove e.async – that will be bad because it's blocking
or: maybe wrap this in a dom-module and import that.